# Access JavaScript json array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this JSON in socket client

```
{ 
  "DATA":
     [
      {
       "message": my_message,
       "name": my_name,
       "id": my_id,
      }
     ]
}
```

And i have to decode this in socket server to respond with another JSON,like below:

```
$data = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
$user_message = $data['DATA']->message; //message text
$user_name = $data['DATA']->name; //sender name
```

But can't access it, What is wrong in it?

Comment: please add param to part json to array json_decode($received_text, true);

Comment: Its an OBJECT so use `$user_message = $data->DATA[0]->message;`

Comment: @HoangHieu what's wrong with using as object?

Comment: @charlietfl Hear Hear, well said

Comment: @RiggsFolly did not work for me

Comment: Why you marked it as duplicated? look it has Key , I could not find any way to solve this problem! What guys you are! @RiggsFolly

Comment: "did not work" is not very helpful, do you get any errors/warnings/notices? If you execute `var_dump($data);` what is the result?

Comment: @rickdenhaan i get null response in server,but without Key i mean "DATA" ,it works without key it was like this {"TEST":test,"TEST1":test1} , note test and test1 are variables.

Comment: If the response is `null` then `json_decode()` failed. You can look at `json_last_error()` to find out why

Comment: When I try to `json_decode()` the json you show us I get `syntax error` from `json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: Maybe if you show us a real json string we can be of assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code like below

```
$received_text =  '{"DATA":[{"message":"my_message","name":"my_name","id":"my_id"}]}';

$data = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
$data = $data->DATA[0];

$user_message = $data->message; //message text
$user_name = $data->name; //sender name 

echo $user_message . "<br>". $user_name;
```

Comment: Please don't beg for up votes. If you want up votes, you can get those by providing higher quality answers. Here it would be useful to tell _what_ you changed, as well as why that fixed the problem. Keep in mind that Q&A's on Stack Overflow are to help the community, not just the OP. (It also strikes me how you were able to answer this question more then 30 minutes after it got closed as a duplicate.)